# Nginx shared hashing across upstream groups

Tags: nginx

We have nginx setup in Azure Kubernetes Services as a LoadBalancer and we are trying to funnel TCP traffic to the same pod based on the client ip. This is across 3 different ports though. We have the following config:

```
stream {
upstream app1 {
    zone app1 256k;

    hash $remote_addr consistent;

    server 10.200.1.50:56000;
    server 10.200.2.10:56000;
    server 10.200.3.15:56000;
    server 10.200.4.20:56000;
}

server {

    listen 56000;
    proxy_pass app1;
}

upstream app2 {
    zone app2 256k;

    hash $remote_addr consistent;

    server 10.200.1.50:56002;
    server 10.200.2.10:56002;
    server 10.200.3.15:56002;
    server 10.200.4.20:56002;
}

server {

    listen 56002;
    proxy_pass app2;
}

upstream app3 {
    zone app3 256k;

    hash $remote_addr consistent;

    server 10.200.1.50:56001;
    server 10.200.2.10:56001;
    server 10.200.3.15:56001;
    server 10.200.4.20:56001;
}

server {

    listen 56001;
    proxy_pass app3;
}


}
```

But unfortunately the hashing appears to resolve to different backends, I assume because the port is different amongst the servers listed in the upstream and that results in different hashing resolutions.

Is there any way to achieve consistent hashing across upstreams? We have separate upstreams because we need the incoming port to be used on the backend server, i.e. if it comes in on port 56001, it needs to be routed to one of the backend servers on port 56001.

We are open to trying a whole other solution if nginx is unable to meet the requirements.